# React: HTML not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rendering

I have this React component whose main goal is to render an article stored ad MarkDown (.md file) after it is transformed into HTML by `marked`.

#### Articles.js

```
import React from 'react';
import marked from 'marked';
import './articles.css';

export default class Articles extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      last_article: ""
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/last_article', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/markdown'
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(txt => marked(txt))
    .then(html => {
      this.setState({
        last_article: html
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="articles">
        {this.state.last_article}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

The back-end works fine and `componentWillMount` fetches the correct text and transforms it perfectly. But it renders like this:

[image]

I am not a React expert and never faced this problem before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render html. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: What Ved said, was just about to post that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` approach as I have described below.

[Go through this link to see the proper documentation about dangerouslySetInnerHTML and it's side effects](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)

```js
class Articles extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      last_article: ""
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({
        last_article: `<h1>Hello</h1>`
      });
    
  }
  
  getMarkdownText() {
    return { __html: this.state.last_article };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="articles" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getMarkdownText()}/> 
      );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Articles />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, dangerouslySetInnerHTML will work, but if you are going to find yourself doing this a lot, [check out this cool lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser).

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it.